# Up button exits app?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm not really sure why this is happening, however I have my Main activity, and then use an Intent to call a child activity.  On this activity I have an up button, however it just exits the app for some reason.  I've been staring at this for a while and maybe it just needs a fresh pair of eyes.

If anyone can explain why this is happening, I'd be grateful

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        cardView.setOnClickListener(new CardView.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Orange.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Orange.java**

```
    public class Orange extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.orange);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

In my AndroidMainfest.xml I have

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Do you have any error log...

Comment: You are finishing Activity when you are starting new Activity. remove `finish();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your MainActivity on button click you do:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Orange.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

You start Orange activity and finish MainActivity. When you exit from Orange, there's nowhere to return, thus the application is closed

Comment: but Orange activity is never being displayed as he describes on his post

Comment: @Alexander Zhak : I think You're right.OP needs to remove that `finish()` line.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but may be its because of **finish();** As finish destroys the activity after moving into another activity ,so you cannot go back to previous activity. Try removing finish (); hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this...

```
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

are you declaring the Orange activity in your manifest?

pleas display your whole android manifest file.

you should have something like:

```
<activity android:name=".Orange"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

in addition to:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
...
```

or else it will crash when you try to start the orange activity.

EDIT:
after re-reading this post I think @Alexander Zhak is correct with his answer, that line (finish();) is closing the first activity so there is nothing to return to so it closes the app.